# Index and count in a range formula

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I try to create a dynamic SUMPRODUCT, for creating the dynamic I need to use other formula in the SUMPRODUCT.
SUMPRODUCT depends from count and match.

Match and count are calculate in G2 and H2. For a dynamic SUMPRODUCT i try the following code

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Work Center KHK'!"D"&G2:"D"&H2;'Work Center KHK'!"E"&G2:"E"&H2)
```

It doesn't work, and I don't If it possible solve the problem. Someone can help me?

Comment: You need `INDIRECT()`. Please post few sample data then show your desired output. Mention your version of excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `=OFFSET(reference, row offset, column offset, height, width)`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET('Work Center KHK'!D1,G2,0,H2,2))
```

You may need to adjust the "top-left" corner (used D1 in formula) according to your own setup.